# Cannot boot after latest windows 8 update - what diagnostic tools to use?

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-update, exceptions

Following the latest Windows 8 update, my computer won't start. I cannot boot from any other USB stick, or a windows 7 DVD. It just says "`MACHINE_CHECK_EXCEPTION`" and it reboots again and again. Windows 7 setup hangs at `"Setup starting..."`.

I removed the graphics card, switched around RAM sticks, underclocked my CPU, took out all the HDDs ... all in vain.

I am looking for a good selection of diagnostic tools that I can install on a USB stick to boot from (hopefully).

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to try using [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com), it has a good collection of software and hardware diagnostics software.

An alternativer could be to use [Knoppix Live CD](http://www.knoppix.org).